# Is referencing a selector faster in jquery than actually calling the selector? if so, how much does it make a difference?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

```
$(preview-button).click(...)
$(preview-button).slide(...)
$(preview-button).whatever(...)
```

Is it a better practice to do this:

```
var preview-button = $(preview-button);
preview-button.click(...);
preview-button.click(...);
preview-button).slide(...);
preview-button.whatever(...);
```

It probably would be better practice to do this for the sake of keeping code clean and modular, BUT does it make a difference performance wise?  Does one take longer to process than the other?  Thanks guys.

Comment: `$(preview-button)` is a syntax error, and while you use the term "selector" in the question it's not clear if you're referring to querying a selector string (eg. `$('#preview-button')`) or wrapping an existing DOM node or jQuery collection (eg. `$(someExistingReference)`). The latter will still be slower than a stored variable, but not so drastic as the former (depending on the selector string and the document).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes it does, when you use the selector without storing it in a variable jQuery needs to parse the DOM EVERY TIME.

If you had something like `$(".class")` jQuery would need to find the elements with that class every time you use it but if it is stored in a variable it uses the unique identifier in the variable. No need to lookup.

So yeah i would totally recommend storing it into a variable.

**UPDATE:**
Added chaining as an alternative.

If you only use the selector in one place you can also do **chaining** which means you add one method after another with the same dot notation like this:

```
$(".class")
       .click(function(){ ... })
       .mouseenter(function(){ ... })
       .css( ... );
```

Comment: I would also recommend chaining as an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You could also chain it:

```
$(preview-button)
    .click(...)
    .slide(...)
    .whatever(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is much faster to use a named variable rather than passing jQuery a selector once for each action. However, as it was already mentioned, chaining is an optimal solution in most cases. You can see it for yourself. Here is a test I just did:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
  //Try changing this value to see what happens as the number of nodes increases or decreases.
  for(i=1;i<2905;i++){
    $('body').append('<div id="'+i+'">'+i+'</div>')
  }
  //Case 1: Query the DOM once for each action
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  $('#2900').css('color','red');
  $('#2900').hide();
  $('#2900').show();
  $('#2900').html(new Date().getTime() - start);

  //Case 2: Chaining. Each method passed $('this') to the next one
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  $('#2901').css('color','blue').hide().show().html(new Date().getTime() - start);

  //Case 3: Use of a named variable
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  var a = $('#2902');
  a.css('color','green');
  a.hide();
  a.show();
  a.html(new Date().getTime() - start);

})
</script>
```

UPDATE:

Apparently Firefox does some kind of caching and the three cases perform very similarly. On the other side Chrome and Safari have a rather poor performance in Case 1, compared against cases 2 and 3 (especially as number or nodes increases).