# Most efficient way to re-use jQuery-selected elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

I can imagine the correct answer to this based on theory, but I'm just looking for some confirmation. I'm wondering what the most efficient way to re-use a jQuery-selected element is. For example:

```
$('#my_div').css('background','red');
//some other code
$('#my_div').attr('name','Red Div');
```

vs.

```
myDiv = $('#my_div');
myDiv.css('background','red');
//some other code
myDiv.attr('name','Red Div');
```

I assume the second example is more efficient because the element #my_div doesn't have to get found more than once. Is that correct?

Similarly, is it more efficient to first save $(this) in a varaible, such as 'obj', and then reuse 'obj' rather than using $(this) over and over? In this case, jQuery isn't being forced to find an element over and over again, but it IS being forced to convert this to a jQuery object [$(this)]. So as a general rule of thumb, should a jQuery object ALWAYS be stored in a variable if it will be used more than once?

Comment: Yes. Don't forget to use `var` though.

Comment: I also like to start the variable name with a $ sign to indicate it is a jQuery object. So rather than myDiv, I would use $myDiv.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654558/is-referencing-a-selector-faster-in-jquery-than-actually-calling-the-selector-if/4654564#4654564

Comment: Yes, the first part is indeed a duplicate of the question you linked to. Sorry about that. However, my related question about $(this) doesn't get covered in that other post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you're using jQuery selector (`like $('#element')`), then yes, you should always store your results.

if you're using object and wrapping it in jQuery (like `$(this)`), it's not necessary, because jQuery doesn't need to search for that element again.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. In @Edwin's example the line `var $this = $(this);` is required if he wants to use jquery methods on <a> element. Within an event hander `this` is a reference to the DOM element, not the jquery object.

Comment: Sure, to use jQuery methods you need to wrap object in jQuery function. But what I meant is that it's not necessary to store such wrappings (like `var obj = $(this)`), because it has little to none impact on performance.

Comment: Answer awarded for being the only one to address the case of $(this)

Comment: *Probably* $(this) is fast, but this answer provides no data to back up that claim.

Answer (score 12):

You should write your code such that you limit the number of DOM traversals.

When you write something like this:

```
$('#my_div').css('background','red');
//some other code
$('#my_div').attr('name','Red Div');
```

You are finding `#my_div` twice, which is inefficient.

You can improve this either by assigning the result of a selector (i.e. `var x = $('.something')`) and manipulate the variable `x`, or you can **chain** your method calls like this:

```
$('#my_div').css('background','red').attr('name','Red Div');
```

You'll see the above code used a lot, because you're finding the element once. The `css()` method will apply a CSS style **and return** the actual result of `$('#my_div')`, so you can invoke another method, in this case `attr()`.

My preferred way of handling the re-use of selectors is to store them as a variable, and wrap my stuff in a closure.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of chaining. That's why I put in the "//some other code" comment to imply that there are things going on between the two times I need to reference #my_div, thereby making chaining not an option. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Answer (score 3):

One thing that I find is generally overlooked is just how powerful jQuery chains are. It may not be so noticeable, but since jQuery caches your wrapped elements within a chain, you can modify elements, go into a more specific subset, modify, then go back up into a a general superset without much overhead.

I expect something like (pardon the example)

```
$('#myDiv')
    .addClass('processing')
    .find('#myInput')
    .hide('slow')
    .end()
    .removeClass('processing')
    ;
```

to be better performance-wise than even

```
var $myDiv = $('#myDiv').addClass('processing');
var $myInput = $('#myDiv #myInput').hide('slow');
    $myDiv.removeClass('processing');
```

Comment: You are the only sane talker here. +1

Answer (score 1):

This also holds for applying the jQuery function to elements returned in an event handler. Try to avoid applying $(...) too many times, because this is slow. Instead create a variable that contains the result of $(...). Good practice is to start the variable with a $, which gives a hint about the jQuery object inside the variable.

```
$('a').click(function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.addClass("clicked");
  $this.attr("clicked", true);
});
```

Comment: Personally, I really hate this practice (it makes my code look like perl), but it's a matter of preference.

Comment: +1 I use `$me` to avoid misreading between `this`, `$(this)` and `$this`. Personal preference.

Comment: On my computer, on Chrome, calling $() to wrap an object can be done 2.6 million times per second, so storing the result of $(this) appears to not be worth the bother.  http://jsperf.com/overhead-of-wrapping-with-jquery