# jQuery, optimal usage question

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I don't know how jQuery works under the hood, but let's say that at some point I create a jQuery object:

```
var thingy = $('#thingy');
```

Further down in the code, is there any difference in reusing `thingy`:

```
thingy.empty();
```

versus just making the jQuery again? :

```
$('#thingy').empty();
```

I guess in the second case, we have to create another jQuery object, but I suspect that is trivial.  What I'm trying to avoid by just reusing the variable is doing a DOM search for matching elements.  Perhaps this search occurs in either case anyway?

My initial assumption was that the the document is scanned upon the creation of the `$` object.  But then it occurred to me that the $ object might just be an iterator that scans the document again every time you execute one of its methods.  I guess this is the crux of my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not so bad if your selector is a single object, but what if your selector is $('.thingy')?  Each time you create it again, it iterates the entire doc looking for that class, rather than using the stored selection.  Not so bad, but then it creates a new DOM object for that selection.  If there's 500 instances of .thingy, that can get really bogged down really quick.

ETA: as no.good.at.coding points out, every time you use a selector of any sort, the entire DOM is traversed.  So yup - store it in a variable, call the variable.

Comment: See that was my initial assumption.  But then it occurred to me that the `$` object might just be an iterator that scans the document again  every time you execute one of its methods.  Are you sure that this isn't the case?

Comment: No, that's not the case. Once you've run a query and cache it, that's it.

Comment: @Brian The answers I've linked to seem to suggest that jQuery might traverse the DOM even when fetching by id.

Comment: @no.good - you're right!  "when you use the selector without storing it in a variable jQuery needs to parse the DOM EVERY TIME."

Comment: @Brian I think I might have misread your answer. It seems like we're both saying the same thing - it's better to cache the jQuery object than using the selector again.

Comment: Aye, that we are - that quote is from the first link you posted.  The only reason selecting by an ID is faster than by class or other selector is because it uses a native javascript method getElementById().  It won't bog down the DOM as quick, even with a lot of usage, because it only returns a single element - but it is still unnecessary overhead.

Answer (score 3):

The answers to these SO questions indicate that it will be faster if you reuse the jQuery object :

- [Is referencing a selector faster in jquery than actually calling the selector? if so, how much does it make a difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654558/is-referencing-a-selector-faster-in-jquery-than-actually-calling-the-selector-if)
- [Most efficient way to re-use jQuery-selected elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5461755/most-efficient-way-to-re-use-jquery-selected-elements)

Answer (score 2):

The other thing to consider is DOM changes. Be sure that, after you set thingy, something doesn't happen that makes $('#thingy') go away!

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you will want to "cache" the results of the selector as long as you're sure they won't be changing.

Your example is fairly trivial, in that the #id selector is already quite efficient (essentially, it just passes it straight to a `document.getElementById()` call.

As others have mentioned, you start to see the savings when you use less performant selectors (such as `$('.class')` ).

By using variables in this way, you're able to save a lot of additional processing. ex:

```
var tree = $('.bigTree');

// Do random stuff with tree
// ...

var segment = tree.find('.subsection');

// Do random stuff with segment...
```

In the above example, the variable "segment" is able to use the results of the variable tree, without having to access the whole DOM again, saving you that bit of performance. While trivial examples like this are rarely worth the effort, making sure you are doing this sort of thing for bits of code (such as loops) can help speed up your application significantly.

Of course, make sure that if you are dynamically updating the DOM, that you are using a "fresh" selector to ensure you pick up any changes :)